# Xamarin.Android How can I set the id of an entry to the generated key from a Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

Im trying to store the unique string on my class in Firebase.

At the minute I am creating new categories as follows

My Class:

```
 public class Category
 {
    public string categoryId { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    //public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
}
```

My Activity:

```
private async void InsertNewCategory()
    {
        Category categories = new Category();
        categories.categoryName = input_newCategory.Text;

        //get the generated key
        //var categoryid = categories.Key;

        var user = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser;

        if (user != null)
        {
            var uid = user.Uid;
            //set the users id to the category
            categories.uid = uid;
        }            

        var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
        var item = await firebase.Child("categories").PostAsync(categories);
    }
```

This is what it looks like in the firebase database:
    [image]

I want to set the categoryId to the key that is generated which makes it unique! Is this possible and if so can I do it as I create the new item?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Push() to obtain the reference "key" before actually storing the data and use it as your `uid`:

#### Using Push() to obtain a "new" database reference:

```
var categoriesRef = firebase.Database.GetReference("categories");
var newReference = categoriesRef.Push();
var category = new Category { categoryId = categoriesRef.Key, categoryName = "StackOverflow", uid = newReference.Key };
await newReference.SetValueAsync(category.Map);

newReference = categoriesRef.Push();
category = new Category { categoryId = categoriesRef.Key, categoryName = "Rocks", uid = newReference.Key };
await newReference.SetValueAsync(category.Map);
```

#### FireBase DB Results:

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "-KrMgASSnq41nxWcDc7H" : {
      "categoryId" : "categories",
      "categoryName" : "StackOverflow",
      "uid" : "-KrMgASSnq41nxWcDc7H"
    },
    "-KrMgBNKh1pNSIyg-DoV" : {
      "categoryId" : "categories",
      "categoryName" : "Rocks",
      "uid" : "-KrMgBNKh1pNSIyg-DoV"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SushilHangover Im getting the error firebase does not contain a definition for Database?

Comment: @Smac It is a member on `DatabaseReference`, i.e. `Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("XXXX").Reference.Database`